# results not print Python - SQlplus

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlplus

I have written the following code to run a script in sqlplus

```
(username, password, host) = ("user","psw","isntance") 
conn_string = " %s/%s@%s "% (username,password,host)
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', conn_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
sql_file = '%s/%s' % ('/my/folder', 'File.sql')
f= open(sql_file,'r')
cmd = f.read()
session.stdin.write(cmd)
stdout, stderr = session.communicate()
```

The code executes without any errors. But I don't see any result being printed.Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code have no print statement. Try following code:

```
(username, password, host) = ("user","psw","isntance") 
conn_string = " %s/%s@%s "% (username,password,host)
session = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', conn_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
sql_file = '%s/%s' % ('/my/folder', 'File.sql')
with open(sql_file) as f:
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate(f.read())
print 'output: %s' % stdout
print 'error: %s' % stderr
```